# Java Eclipse Class Comparing Marks And Displaying Who Failed

Tags: java, eclipse

In this code I want to compare all 4 test students and display who failed. I need help in only Failed Class. The topper class is fine.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentClass {

static ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();

static void Student() {

Student topper = list.get(0);
for(int i=1;i<list.size();++i){
if(topper.marks<list.get(i).marks){
topper = list.get(i);
}
}
System.out.println("tooper is : "+topper.name);

}

static void failed1(){

if(list.get(i)<=35 ){
}
}


// System.out.println("This Student Failed" +);



public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

Student s = new Student();
s.name = "Test 1";
s.roolno = 1;
s.marks = 30.5f;

list.add(s);
Student x = new Student();
x.name = "Test 2";
x.roolno = 2;
x.marks = 32.5f;

list.add(x);
Student y = new Student();
y.name = "Test 3";
y.roolno = 3;
y.marks = 80.5f;

list.add(y);
Student z = new Student();
z.name = "Test 4";
z.roolno = 4;
z.marks = 90.5f;

list.add(z);
printMainMenu();
}

private static void printMainMenu() {
System.out.println("** Main Menu **");
System.out.println("1.Topper");
System.out.println("2. Student Who Failed");
System.out.println("3.Exit");
System.out.println("\nEnter your Choice");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int ch = in.nextInt();
switch (ch) {
case 1:
Student();
break;
case 2:
failed1();
break;
case 3:
System.exit(0);
default:
System.out.println("Enter Vaild Press Enter To Continue");
try {
System.in.read();

clear();
printMainMenu();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.setStackTrace(null);
}

break;

}
}

private static void clear() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private static void failed() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
// private static void Entering(String string) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

Comment: Please post an actual question, including any code needed to explain it, not just a link. First reduce the code to as little as possible to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Looks like you should implement a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)  for 
the `Student` class .. here is an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

Comment: Please post the student class as well

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can do the checks. The simplest of course is a manual check

```
    ArrayList<Student> failedStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();

    for (Student student : studentList)
    {
        if (student.getMark() < passMark )
        {
            failedStudents.add(student);  
        }
    }
```

You can also implement a [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) with a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) class that orders `Student` objects by marks.